# Looping variables as element names in R?

Tags: r

This has been a problem that I've encountered in other languages but at the moment I'm dealing in R. For example, if you have a list containing 3 other lists named "a", "b", and "c", is there a way to iterate through `list("a","b","c")` and use the iterating variable as the name of the element of the first list?

```
testlist = list("a"=list(1,2,3),"b"=list(4,5,6),"c"=list(7,8,9))
for (i in c("a","b","c")){
  print(testlist$i)
}
```

instead of

```
print(testlist$a)
print(testlist$b)
print(testlist$c)
```

I've tried casting `as.name(i)` etc. but get `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
lapply(testlist, print)
```

2nd option with a lot more room to expand - the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)
walk(testlist, print)
```

The `walk` specifically let's you do something like make a graph, print, or save output where you don't need to return anything.  More generally, the primary function for returning output is `map`, but the package does a lot more: it has options which let you reference the `a`, `b`, and `c` labels (`imap`), apply a function which takes inputs from two different lists (`map2`), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using your same example, you can do

```
testlist = list("a"=list(1,2,3),"b"=list(4,5,6),"c"=list(7,8,9))
for (i in c("a","b","c")){
  print(testlist[[i]])
}
```

Comment: I'm aware you can iterate over the index of the list, but I was wondering if there's any way to specifically iterate over the name of the index?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean. In the example above, `i` equals the name of the index ("a", "b", or "c"). You can select an element either as `testlist[[1]]` or `testlist[["a"]]`. Am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do?